# Error in Android Java Retrofit : expected begin_object but was number at line 1 column 5 path $

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have trouble getting int from the server :(
Thanks for guiding me

**Error in Android Java Retrofit : expected begin_object but was number at line 1 column 5 path $**

Server code:

```
    <?php
require('con.php');
$user_email=$_REQUEST['user_email'];
$sql = "SELECT SUM(add_pay) AS sum FROM  Tbl_tarakonesh WHERE user_email = '$user_email'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response=array();
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$jam=$row['sum'];
echo $jam;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

```
public class Model_kol
{
    @SerializedName("jam")
    private int jam;
    public int getJam() {
        return jam;
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface MyService {

    @GET("show_kol_tarakonesh.php")
    Call<Model_kol> reg(@Query("user_email") String email);
}
```

---

onActivity :

```
apiInterface = ApiClient_Kol.getApiClient().create(MyService.class);
        Call<Model_kol> call = this.apiInterface.reg(hw_information.check_hq("tx_email"));

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Model_kol>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Model_kol> call, Response<Model_kol> response) {
              //  Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(),"OK :))",LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(),response.body().getJam()+"",LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Model_kol> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(),"Failure" + "/n" + t.toString(),LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Upload your api response. Error says that it expecting object but api response is number.

Comment: Check ur query in php again

Comment: Your api response not a JSON format.